# Where and how to use HttpResponse in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-http

`HttpResponse` class(in **@angular/common/http**) is a replace of class `Response` of **@angular/http**(which is deprecated). Looking at docs don't give much idea of how and where to use it! Moreover, I tried to replace my old angular code but since this class is generic so it needs a type e.g. `HttpResponse<T>`. Giving it type  gives an error as :

`Property 'json' does not exist on type 'HttpResponse<any>'`

Can anyone please help me know how to use HttpResponse class in angular?

**UPDATE**

This is my code snippet, a function 'get', that I made:

```
get(path: string, params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(`${environment.api_url}${path}`, { headers: this.setHeaders(), search: params })
  .catch(this.formatErrors)
  .map((res: HttpResponse<any>) => res.json());
```

Comment: when we are using `HttpClient` module you need not convert to `json`. The response is by default converted to json

Comment: Did you try these docs https://angular.io/guide/http ? Can you post more code from you http call

Comment: @Alexander : updated!

Answer (score 11):

[HttpResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse) as per docs is:

> A full HTTP response, including a typed response body (which may be null >if one was not returned).
>
> `HttpResponse` is a `HttpEvent` available on the response event stream.

As per your specific problem that you are facing - `T` refers to generic type which is meant for the `body` property of `HttpResponse`.

```
class HttpResponse<T> extends HttpResponseBase {
  constructor(init: {...})
  get body: T|null
  ...
```

So if your variable is `res: HttpResponse<any>` and you are trying to access `json` property like `res.json` will not work because `HttpResponse` doesn't have property `json`. You need to access `body` and then `json`.

```
(res:HttpResponse<any>) => console.log(res.body.json)
```

In addition, a good example where you use `HttpResponse` is [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor). Interceptors intercepts and update the response and/or request event stream. And with `HttpResponse` and `HttpRequest` you can detect which stream event to handle using `event instanceof`.

Here is example of an interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class EmptyResponseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const newReq = req.clone({
      responseType: 'text'
    });

    return next.handle(newReq).map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        let newEvent: HttpEvent<any>;

        // alter response here. maybe do the following
        newEvent = event.clone({ 
          // alter event params here
        });
        
        return newEvent;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this answer is not working for me so I had to use solution like below.

```
return next.handle(changedReq)
           .pipe(
                 catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                  if(error.status == 401 && error.statusText == "Unauthorized"){
                    this.jwtAuth.signout();
                  }
                    let errorMsg = '';
                    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
                       console.log('This is client side error');
                       errorMsg = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
                    } else {
                       console.log('This is server side error');
                       errorMsg = `Error Code: ${error.status},  Message: ${error.message}`;
                    }
                    console.log(errorMsg);
                    return throwError(errorMsg);
                 })
           )
```